# Java apache Httpclient form-based login myspace

Tags: java, forms, apache, authentication, httpclient

So I am trying to login to a website (in this example myspace) using Apache's HttpClient v.4 but I am not sure where I am going wrong in the process, when I test this code, the Post Login Cookies are the same as the Initial login cookies, but that shouldn't be.

I have looked around online to see if anyone else has tried, but I haven't found a good resource that has worked for me.

I am using this example: [apache HttpClient to access facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902013/apache-httpclient-to-access-facebook) ( Facebook)

```
 try{
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.myspace.com/auth/form");

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
        if (entity != null) {
            entity.consumeContent();
        }
        System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
        List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
            }
        }

        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://www.myspace.com/auth/form");

        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "someEmail"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "somePassword"));

        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

        response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        entity = response.getEntity();
        //System.out.println("Double check we've got right page " + EntityUtils.toString(entity));

        System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
        if (entity != null) {
            entity.consumeContent();
        }

        System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
        cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Example cookie:

```
    [version: 0][name: MSCOUNTRY][value: US][domain: .myspace.com][path: /][expiry: Tue Jun 12 23:22:15 EDT 2012]
[version: 0][name: MSCulture][value: IP=XXX.XXX.XXXX&IPCulture=en-US&PreferredCulture=en-US&PreferredCulturePending=&Country=VVM=&ForcedExpiration=0&timeZone=0&myStuffDma=&myStuffMarket=&USRLOC=RandomUserLocString==&UserFirstVisit=1][domain: .myspace.com][path: /][expiry: Tue Jun 12 23:22:15 EDT 2012]
[version: 0][name: SessionDDF2][value: RandomStringHere==][domain: .myspace.com][path: /][expiry: Sat Jun 05 23:22:15 EDT 2032]
```

Comment: What cookie(s) is/are missing, and how do you know they're missing?

Comment: When it prints out the Initial cookies and then the Post login cookies, they are the same, so I am assuming that that means it did not login properly.

Comment: But does it actually not login properly?

Comment: I really don't know if it is logging in properly or not, that is what I am kind of getting at.

Comment: How about trying something after you try logging in? Or looking at the response to see what has happened?

Comment: After I login using this code, I then go in and create a new Url for someones page and I then get that HTML, but you have to be logged in to see the profile, so after using this code it still fails. What I am wondering is do I have to pass the cookie to the new Url (and a UrlConnection) or should it work fine if I just try and get the HTMl for a new Url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that the initial cookies and the post cookies should be different? The application server side assigns a set of cookies to the client and usually that stays the same throughout the session.

The application server associates a set of attributes associated with the session (using cookies as a lookup), and that is what decides whether the session is 'logged-in' or not.

Comment: So should I take these cookies and pass them to each new URLConnection that I create? Because at this point, when I create a new URL the session is not saved.

Comment: Yes. In order for the app-server to identify a "session", you need to hand the cookies associated with the "session" in your URLConnection.

Comment: Take a look at my Original Post with the cookies that I have pasted, would I have to add all three of those to the URLConnection? Because just adding the last line did not work. I'm using this code: urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", myCookie); but it says for multiple cookies (http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html) to put them in with ;'s

Comment: I also tried doing urlConn.setRequestProperty("SessionDDF2",valueOfThirdCookie); but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is not mention here is that in order to successfully open an authenticated `URLConnection` you will need to set the cookies you received after the authentication on the 
`URLConnection`:

```
    URL myUrl = new URL("http://yourdomain/your/page);

    URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();

    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookies.get(i).getName() + "=" + cookies.get(i).getValue());
    }
    urlConn.connect();

    InputStream io = (InputStream) urlConn.getContent();


    // print out the response
    List<String> readLines = IOUtils.readLines(io);

    for (String line : readLines) {
        System.out.println (line);
    }
```