# HttpClientFormSubmit to get the OAUTH access token

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using httpcomponents-client-4.2.5-bin for the ClientFormSubmit. I used the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902013/apache-httpclient-to-access-facebook) to login to facebook using Oauth. My Oauth login has following steps

1. first login to facebook using

   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/
2. give the login details it redirects to the local host and have code parameter in url

I need to get that code value.

Code is

```
 try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=358300034293206&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/");

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
        if (entity != null) {
            entity.consumeContent();
        }
        System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
        List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
            }
        }

        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=358300034293206&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/");

        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "*****"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "*****"));

        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

        response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("Double check we've got right page " + EntityUtils.toString(entity));

        System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
        if (entity != null) {
            entity.consumeContent();
        }

        System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
        cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
            }
        }

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println( "Something bad just happened." );
            System.out.println( e );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Is it possible to get the redirect url using request header? Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HttpClient 4.3 APIs

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/");
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);
try {
    System.out.println("Response status: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine());
    System.out.println("Last request URI: " + context.getRequest().getRequestLine());
    URICollection redirectLocations = context.getRedirectLocations();
    if (redirectLocations != null) {
        System.out.println("All intermediate redirects: " + redirectLocations.getAll());
    }
    EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity());
} finally {
    httpResponse.close();
}
```

Using HttpClient 4.2 APIs

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/");
try {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);
    System.out.println("Response status: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine());
    HttpRequest req = (HttpRequest) context.getAttribute(
            ExecutionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
    System.out.println("Last request URI: " + req.getRequestLine());
    RedirectLocations redirectLocations = (RedirectLocations) context.getAttribute(
            DefaultRedirectStrategy.REDIRECT_LOCATIONS);
    if (redirectLocations != null) {
        System.out.println("All intermediate redirects: " + redirectLocations.getAll());
    }
    EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity());
} finally {
    httpGet.releaseConnection();
}
```