# Logging in to facebook using apache HTTP client

Tags: facebook, post, cookies, get, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to write automated tests for a REST API using apache HTTP client, we are using Facebook as an affiliate to log in.

I have used this question as a starting point:

[apache HttpClient to access facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902013/apache-httpclient-to-access-facebook)

But it is using lots of deprecated methods.

I have switched all of these out but I am finding that it is not working.

to validate I have written a method to print out the body response and I am viewing that by making it into a HTML document. When I load that page it has the facebook error message of:

Cookies Required
Cookies are not enabled on your browser. Please enable cookies in your browser preferences to continue.

My code:

```
CookieStore cs = new BasicCookieStore();
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.facebook.com/login.php");

    HttpResponse response= HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(cs).build().execute(httpget);

    System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());

    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://www.facebook.com/login.php");
    context.setCookieStore(cs);
    List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "******"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "*****"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lsd", "AVptst2v"));
    httpost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    httpost.setHeader("Host", "www.facebook.com");
    httpost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    httpost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    httpost.setHeader("Cookie", cs.toString());
    httpost.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    httpost.setHeader("Referer", "https://www.facebook.com/login");
    httpost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
    response = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(cs).build().execute(httpost,context);

    System.out.println("Login form post: " + response.getStatusLine());
    System.out.println(printBodyOfResponse(response));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I found that creating a context and passing that through with each request carried the session, I see lots of answers saying that cookie management is automatic, but for me the only solution was to pass the context throughout

```
    BasicHttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.facebook.com/login.php");

    HttpResponse response= HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(get,context);

    System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());

    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");
    List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",PropertiesUtil.loadSiteProperty("FB_email")));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", PropertiesUtil.loadSiteProperty("FB_password")));
    httpost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    httpost.setHeader("Host", "www.facebook.com");
    httpost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    httpost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    httpost.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    httpost.setHeader("Referer", "https://www.facebook.com/login");
    httpost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));

    response = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(httpost,context);
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "PropertiesUtil.loadSiteProperty", but if you put your credentials as plain text there, it's still not working, showing "Cookies Required" error message.

Comment: This used to work for me so maybe they have changed something on their end now